# Remove blankspace from td class with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

If I have webpage with for example alot of `<td class="house">111 22</td>`. The numbers are random but classname is the same and the blankspace between the numbers are at same position in all of them, and I want to remove the space in all of them after page is loaded. How should the script look like to work?

Comment: You can't edit the text *"before it renders"*. Greasemonkey scripts are executed after page load (Not to mention the fact you can't modify content that doesn't exist yet)

Answer (score 0):

How about using this

```
var str = "111 22";    
    str = str.replace(" ","");
```

code example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //Page Initial
 $(function() {
     removeSpace();
 });
 function removeSpace(){
   var str = $(".house").html();
       str = str.replace(" ","");
       $(".house").html(str);
 }

</script>
```

Comment: And if the numbers are random, what regex can I use to match five digits in that order with a blankspace between the first three and last two?

Comment: Or you can plug-in [link](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) 'sprintf' @user3509693

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('td.house');
for(var i = 0 ; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].textContent = elems[i].textContent.replace(" ","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    use the following code:

   <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = removeSpace;

    function removeSpace() {
        var emt = document.getElementById("mytable");//mytable is the Id of the table
        d = emt.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0],
         r = d.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            var str = r[i].innerText;
            r[i].innerText = str.replace(" ", "");
        }
    }

</script>
```