# Remove blankspace from postalcodes on webpage with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I got a webpage with alot of random postalcodes that look like this on a webpage that are spread out:
423 43 
324 42 
123 45 
342 39 
etc
What code can I use to remove only the blankspace from all of them between the first three digits and the last two. 
Ex 123 45 -> 12345

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove blankspace from td class with greasemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929488/remove-blankspace-from-td-class-with-greasemonkey)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a string replace regex.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/E8gHR/

For example:

```
$('span').each(function(){
    var number = $(this).text().replace(/(\d\d\d)(\s)(\d\d)/g, '$1'+'$3'); 
    $(this).text(number);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to a fiddle? Or can you give more details on how you need this to work? 
The above function only works if you pass the numbers through with the space, and returns the number without the space.

Comment: These postalcodes that consist of three random digits followed by a blankspace and then two random digits. Appear in a <span></span> on a webpage with other random text etc. But what I want is to remove only the blankspace between those three random digits and the two random digits. Ex <span>randomtext 10 b, 802 77 randomtext</span> I want it to be <span>randomtext 10 b, 80277 randomtext</span>

Comment: I've edited my answer based on the info you provided, and added a link to a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a code to remove spaces from ONE string.

```
var str = '123 45'; 
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // removing all White-spaces from the string
```

If you want to remove all white-spaces/spaces from  all the strings at the same time, than I have to see the HTML to work something out

Good luck

:)